# Is it feasible to implement analog-style spectrum analyzer and sliding DFT as visualizations in music players?

Tags: fft, dft, software-implementation

The [real-time constant-Q transform](https://codepen.io/TF3RDL/pen/MWLzPoO) are possible using sliding DFT (sDFT) because unlike FFT, sDFT can have arbitrary frequency scale and variable per-bin window size, and of course, the realtime CQT can also be more efficiently approximated using analog-style IIR bandpass filters. However, it requires the audio data stream to be contiguous in-order to be calculated properly (which I meant that it probably don't work naively with non-contiguous streams like `AnalyserNode.getFloatTimeDomainData()` that I used on my FFT visualizations), which AFAIK, most media players doesn't support sDFT nor time-domain filter bank natively for visualizations and it needs to use tricks involving delta thing (difference between current and previous frame) [something like this](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,125031.msg1039011.html#msg1039011) in-order to work.

And if it is feasible, what are limitations when comes to implementing sliding DFT as media player visualizations in general, not just foobar2000 (perhaps a [CQT/VQT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-Q_transform) spectrum analyzer)?

And also is this above a reason why we don't see spectrum analyzers that has logarithmic frequency resolution inside media players (like a foobar2000 component that implements)?

Comment: I think there are spectrum analyzers in the professional audio market that do real-time sliding FFT.

Comment: Although they do exist (e.g. [Sb-sDFT](https://github.com/7ERr0r/sbsdft) and [Pianolizer](https://github.com/creaktive/pianolizer)), I want to clarify that there's is no known spectrum visualization plugins for media players like foobar2000 that uses sliding DFT to calculate CQT/VQT in real-time

Comment: What'sa CQT or VQT?

Comment: [CQT/VQT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-Q_transform) are similar to Fourier transform but with the big difference is that frequency scale for bin spacing is usually logarithmic and it has different window sizes per-bin (which is contrast to linearly-spaced FFT, and it is not easily invertible as of result, which I don't care for visualizations)

Comment: What's the "V" mean?

Comment: Variable-Q transform (VQT) are a variant of CQT where frequency resolution is neither linear nor logarithmic, which are used if you want to sacrifice frequency resolution for better temporal resolution for bass frequencies as the frequency resolution scale is neither linear nor logarithmic